# image threshold in skimage or pure python

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, computer-vision, scikit-image

In one code segment, open cv uses

```
import cv2
img = cv2.threshold(img, 0.5, 1., cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1].astype(np.uint8)
```

In skimage or pure Python, are there any efficient ways or existing functions that achieve the same goal as the above open cv (cv2) usage?

Comment: For those of us who know 'pure Python(?)' more than `cv2`, can you describe what that does?  What's the nature of `img`?

Answer (score 0):

In `skimage` you are supposed to use `skimage.filters` to be able to use all threshold related functions available.

```
from skimage import data
from skimage.filters import try_all_threshold

img = data.page()

fig, ax = try_all_threshold(img, figsize=(10, 8), verbose=False)
plt.show()
```

Visit [THIS PAGE](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/xx_applications/plot_thresholding.html)

The crux is, in OpenCV there is just a single function involved. In `skimage` you have to import the `filter` module **explicitly** in order to perform threshold operations.

*You can also perform threshold operations using `PIL` (Python Imaging Library).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to threshold using only Python (apart from reading and writing and viewing the result)

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2

# read image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg',0)

# threshold
img_thresh = img
img_thresh[ img < 128 ] = 0
img_thresh[ img_thresh >= 128 ] = 255

# view result
cv2.imshow("threshold", img_thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save result
cv2.imwrite("lena_threshold.jpg", img_thresh)
```

[image]